# incrementing index in each loop jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a json file that contains paths to many images that I wish to add more image paths to occasionally. I am making a `GET` request to this file and adding the images to a html page. The issue I am having is using the `$.each` method is that the index is remaining the same, meaning that each image is repeated in each row, however what I want to do is append 3 different images in each row.

I know I can put `[index+1]` etc. however this will not scale the more images I have.

I hope this makes sense. If not let me know and I can provide more details.

Please see code below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="portrait-page"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$.get('json/categories.json', function( data ){
    $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
        $('.portrait-page .container').append( "<div class='grid'><div class='col-1-3'><img src='" + data[index].image + "''></div><div class='col-1-3'><img src='" + data[index].image + "''></div><div class='col-1-3'><img src='" + data[index].image + "''></div></div>");
    });
});
```

**JSON file**

```
[
    {"image":"images/geysir.jpg"},
    {"image":"images/burren.jpg"},
    {"image":"images/cuba.jpg"},
    {"image":"images/london.jpg"},
    {"image":"images/vegas.jpg"},
    {"image":"images/cliff.jpg"},
    {"image":"images/timbaland.jpg"},
    {"image":"images/burren.jpg"},
    {"image":"images/che.jpg"}
]
```

**CSS**

```
[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
}
.col-1-3 {
    width: 33.33%;
}
.grid:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
*, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
[class*='col-'] {
    padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}
.col-1-3 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: index will increment automatic , try data[0]  ,,, may be your data contain 1 array element which have multiple images elements

Comment: Why are you appending them in groups of three when you aren't doing anything in the markup that actually groups them by three? Why not just one at a time?

Comment: @phantom : Why can't you append one by one. That will do the same thing.

Comment: Why use `$.each`? Just iterate in a simple `for` loop with a `index+=3` incrementer

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to achieve... why is '3' the magic number? can it be dynamic?

Comment: @RonenCypis I am grouping them in three as there is a 3 column grid. I removed some of the html to make the question more readable. Apologies for causing confusion with this

Comment: @phantom just updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to do multiple images per iteration, you don't want `$.each`, you want your own loop.

You might do something like this:

If you **know** `data.length` will be an exact multiple of 3:

```
$.get('json/categories.json', function( data ){
    var container = $(".portrait-page .container");
    var markup;
    var index = 0;
    while (index < data.length) {
        markup = "<div class='grid'>";
        for (var n = 0; n < 3; ++n) {
            markup += "<div class='col-1-3'><img src='" + data[index++].image + "'></div>";
        }
        markup += "</div>";
        container.append(markup);
    }
});
```

If you don't, we just throw in an `if`:

```
$.get('json/categories.json', function( data ){
    var container = $(".portrait-page .container");
    var markup;
    var img;
    var index = 0;
    while (index < data.length) {
        markup = "<div class='grid'>";
        for (var n = 0; n < 3; ++n) {
            if (index < data.length) {
                img = "<img src='" + data[index++].image + "'>";
            } else {
                img = "";
            }
            markup += "<div class='col-1-3'>" + img + "</div>";
        }
        markup += "</div>";
        container.append(markup);
    }
});
```

Example:

```js
var data = JSON.parse(
  '[' +
  '{"image":"one"},' +
  '{"image":"two"},' +
  '{"image":"three"},' +
  '{"image":"four"},' +
  '{"image":"five"},' +
  '{"image":"six"},' +
  '{"image":"seven"}' +
  ']'
);
var container = $(".portrait-page .container");
var markup;
var img;
var index = 0;
while (index < data.length) {
  markup = "<div class='grid'>";
  for (var n = 0; n < 3; ++n) {
    if (index < data.length) {
      img = "[img src='" + data[index++].image + "']";
    } else {
      img = "";
    }
    markup += "<div class='col-1-3'>" + img + "</div>";
  }
  markup += "</div>";
  container.append(markup);
}
```

```css
div.col-1-3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="portrait-page">
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: they are grouped in three as there is a three column grid

Comment: @phantom: There may be CSS at play doing that, but nothing in the markup you showed does. If CSS or some such does, you don't need to append them in groups of three. Your code is just appending `<img ...>` three times, then three times more, but that's the same as appending `<img ...>` six times individually (other than it being slightly more work for the browser, which is unlikely to matter).

Comment: i want them as a three column grid, but the same image is going into each row three times, but i want to change the image each time

Comment: I have updated the question, might make more sense now

Comment: @phantom: Yes, **that** changes things. :-) I'll update the answer.

Comment: Whoops! sorry, in my silly head it all seemed so obvious! sorry!

Comment: @phantom: Updated the answer. :-)

Comment: thanks! great answer! works a charm! :-) absolute legend!

Comment: for some reason that is missing 2 of the images on each loop! :-( so weird if i do `console.log(data[index++].image)` just in the first line after the loop declaration it works! completely confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118407/discussion-between-phantom-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: @phantom: I've added an example demonstrating the above code working to the answer. Good luck!

Comment: To be honest, why would you want to use 2 loops (of which one is nested) for something that can be done in 1? It might only be a small performance impact, but it is a performance impact nonetheless...

Comment: @GerritBertier: There's no performance impact above at all. If you didn't use two loops, you'd need another conditional, which would cost at least what the nested loop costs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$.each(data, function( index, value ) {
    if((index + 1) % 3 == 0){
       $('.portrait-page').append( "<img src=" + data[index-2].image + "><img src='" + data[index-1].image + "><img src=" + data[index].image + ">");
    }
});
```

OR

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length - 3; i+=3){
   $('.portrait-page').append( "<img src=" + data[i].image + "><img src='" + data[i+1].image + "><img src=" + data[i+2].image + ">");
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I haven't tested it but I'm not sure why it won't work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't think it will skip the first index because I'm using `(index+1)%3` the first time this condition will be `true` is when the `index` will be `2`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes that is correct but `(2 + 1) % 3 == 0` is true and I'm using `index - 2, index - 1 and index` which means `0, 1, 2`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're doing there.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that you just render all of the images from the json file into the `.portrait-page` element, Your loop should look like this:

```
var $container = $('.portrait-page');
$.get('json/categories.json', function( data ){
    $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
        $container.append( "<img src=" + value.image + " />");
    });
});
```

If for some reason you want to render them in batches of 3, you should do:

```
var $container = $('.portrait-page');
$.get('json/categories.json', function( data ){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length - 3; i+=3){
        var $grid = $('<div />').addClass('grid');
        $grid.append( "<img src=" + data[i].image + " />")
             .append( "<img src=" + data[i+1].image + " />")
             .append( "<img src=" + data[i+2].image + " />")
             .appendTo($container);
    });
});
```

Comment: this does the same thing as before, shows the same image

Comment: @phantom, this renders all of the images from the json file, without repeating the `"<img... />"` part and without touching the `index` var...

Comment: @phantom check the second half of my answer

Answer (score 0):

dont use this

```
$('.portrait-page').append( "<img src=" + data[index].image + "><img src='" + data[index].image + "><img src=" + data[index].image + ">");
```

well you have to get values using value not data 

just give console.log and check whats coming in value.image to get better idea

```
   $('.portrait-page').append( "<img src=" + value.image + "><img src='" + value.image + "><img src=" + value.image + ">");
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong using `$.each` at all, the `index` should increment nicely as well.

Since you need to create DOM anyway, you can do it in the loop, just use the `%` operator to check for every third item. If it's a 3rd item, add the complete row to the wrapper and create a new DOM object for a new row.

**jQuery**

```
var $htmlEl = $('.portrait-page');
var $rowEl = $('<div class="grid"></div>');
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  $rowEl.append('<div class="col-1-3"><img src="' + value.image + '" /></div>');
  if (((index + 1) % 3) === 0) {
    $htmlEl.append($rowEl);
    $rowEl = $('<div class="grid"></div>');
  }
});
```

**And the complete Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/wtg1trjn/1/

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a job for a `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++){
   $('.portrait-page').append( "<img src=" + data[i].image + ">");
}
```